# Payum error after composer update

Tags: php, symfony, payum

Im using Payum bundle for symfony2 like 4 months. Is working fine but yesterder after a `composer update` the symfony2 console throws me an error.

> [Payum\Core\Exception\RuntimeException]
>       Cannot find gateway factory class. Have you installed payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp or payum/payum package?

I didnt change anything on my config or my bundles.

My composer.json is:

```
    "payum/payum-bundle": "*@stable",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "*@stable",
```

I use `express-checkout-nvp` for my application.

And my config for gateways is like that:

```
 gateways:
    paypal_express_checkout:
        paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
            username:  '%paypal.express_checkout.username%'
            password:  '%paypal.express_checkout.password%'
            signature: '%paypal.express_checkout.signature%'
            sandbox: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Okey, changing versions in composer.json it worked.

```
    "payum/payum-bundle": "^1.0",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.0"
```

Thanks to all, hope it helps anyone.